# WebElement is stale when navigating to facebook/twitter then back to original page in Sauce Labs Selenium using AndroidDriver

Tags: java, android, selenium, junit, saucelabs

I have a selenium test failing on Sauce Labs due to a stale element.  The test opens up a page, clicks on a few links within the site, click on a link that takes you to Facebook, then back and that's where things stop working.  For some reason after coming back to the original page, the driver is no longer able to find "fresh" elements.  This seem to be only happening when using Android on Sauce Labs.  The code is below, please let me know if you have any suggestions for how to work around it (I don't care if it is perfect at this point, just want to get it working).

```
@Test
public void testFooter() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");

    // these links are all on my domain, work just fine
    driver.findElement(linkText("About Us")).click();
    driver.findElement(linkText("Press")).click();
    driver.findElement(linkText("Careers")).click();
    driver.findElement(linkText("FAQ")).click();
    driver.findElement(linkText("Industry Resources")).click();
    driver.findElement(linkText("Share")).click();

    // going out to facebook works
    driver.findElement(linkText("Facebook")).click();
    driver.navigate().back();

    // coming back to the page and clicking the twitter link fails due to 
    // org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: WebElement is stale.
    driver.findElement(linkText("Twitter")).click();
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Comment: If you change from linkText to cssSelector does that work better?

Comment: @bcar that did not help, same error: stale element.

Comment: If you add driver.manage.refresh() (believe thats the call) does it work if you refresh page?

Comment: @bcar tried `driver.navigate().refresh();`, didn't help. I think the issue is specific to AndroidDriver and unfortunately SauceLabs has no plans to switch to Selendroid. Thanks for your help anyway, I learned a few new commands in the process.